# Error startActivity in a Service etends with API 23 or lower

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-manifest

I have a service with a Thread where i  sometimes need to call the startActivity method and it would work fine when i use with API 24>, but when i use with API 23 or lower it won't work.

Code in class Thread:

```
private Intent itBlock= null;
itBlock = new Intent ( getApplicationContext (), BlockActivity.class );
startActivity ( itBlock );
```

Manifest have:

```
 <activity android:name=".activities.BlockActivity"/>
```

LogCat error:

```
at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:338)
```

Does anyone know how to proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to call startActivity with application context, include the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.

```
itBlock.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```